# Yup validation cyclic depedency with 2 fields linked to each other

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I have string input that are not required unless one of them is required.

I can't see any way to do this since yup raise a Cyclic depedency error with this code :

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    morning_start: yup.string().when("morning_end", {
      is: (morning_end) => morning_end.length > 0,
      then: () => yup.string().required("This is reqiured"),
    }),
    morning_end: yup.string().when("morning_start", {
      is: (morning_start) => morning_start.length > 0,
      then: () => yup.string().required("This is reqiured"),
    }),
  });
```